# db2wh docker pull failed

Tags: docker, dashdb

Trying to install Db2wh but not getting the docker pull

docker run -d -it --privileged=true --net=host --name=Db2wh -v /mnt/clusterfs:/mnt/bludata0 -v /mnt/clusterfs:/mnt/blumeta0 store/ibmcorp/db2wh_ee:v2.10.0-db2wh-linux

What does this mean?
repository docker.io/store/ibmcorp/db2wh_ee not found: does not exist or no pull access

Answer (score 0):

Did you subscribe to the Db2wh product on Docker store? You need to click on "checkout" button and complete the subscription process before pulling the image. If you are getting this error even after subscribing then there might be a problem at Docker's side.

Comment: If possible, ask followup questions in comments before you post your answer.

Comment: yes I have completed the checkout and it is showing as active in my contents on the docker store.  What can I look at in my docker install to find out why its not connecting properly to the enterprise store

Comment: Is this still an issue for you? If you have "Enterprise Edition" of "IBM Db2 Warehouse" in your docker store My Content, and you have used the same docker to login from you shell `docker login -u=<docker_id> -p='<password>'`  it should work for you.    BTW v2.11.0 is now the latest release